# Loop output from ansible module hcloud_server

Tags: ansible

This is the loop output from the task of creating a virtual server.
[loop in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/RT5habHP)

I have some debug task to separate IP and password from all data.

```
- name: Display password of new server
  debug:
  msg: Ip of server is - {{ results | map(attribute='hcloud_server') | map(attribute='ipv4_address') }} and password is - {{ results | map(attribute='root_password') }}
  register: access_password
```

After this task I have some text output when I send it to email from Ansible `{'msg': "Ip of server is - ['11.111.111.181'] and password is - ['DFDFDFDFDFDFDFDF']", 'failed': False, 'changed': False}`

Could you help, How I can to eliminate `{'msg':` and `, 'failed': False, 'changed': False}` using grep and regex? Is this possible to use grep after command `msg`?

Send email task with module community.general.mail:

```
  community.general.mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: mail@gmail.com
    password: pass
    to:John Smith <user@mail.com>
    subject: Server was created
    body: Server with name {{ item.name }} has been successfully created. Properties of server - "{{ cx11 }}"
    body: "{{ access_password }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use set fact instead register debug:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Display password of new server
      set_fact: 
        access_password: Ip of server is - {{ results | map(attribute='hcloud_server') | map(attribute='ipv4_address') }} and password is - {{ results | map(attribute='root_password') }}
```

or if you want to keep the result of debug, use  `access_password.msg`

```
body: "{{ access_password.msg }}"
```